# Как сконвертировать png изображение в txt файл с шестнадцатиричным кодом и обратно?

Tags: javascript, node.js, изображения, hex, fstream

Есть вот такая картинка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть вот такой код node.js:

```js
const fs = require('fs');

let read_stream = fs.createReadStream('image.png');
read_stream.on('data', (data) => {
    fs.writeFileSync('hex_image.txt', data.toString('hex'));
});
```

В итоге получаю длинный-длинный файл, который мне и нужен был:
`"89504e470d0a1a0a0000000d49..."`, но как из этого получить обратно картинку?

Если так:

```js
let read_stream = fs.createReadStream('hex_image.txt');
read_stream.on('data', (data) => {
    fs.writeFileSync('copy.png', data);
});
```

То в файл `copy.png` помещается hex, но уже другой: `"cfe18d1bb780767955c418..."`